# How to ensure template helper has data?

Tags: asynchronous, meteor, meteor-blaze

I have a select box that runs a small method on each option to determine what 'selected' is:

```
      <label for="soft-due-date-controller">Soft Due Days:</label>
      <select class="form-control" id="soft-due-date-controller">
        <option value="0" {{determineDefaultSelect '0'}}>0</option>
        <option value="1" {{determineDefaultSelect '1'}}>1</option>
        <option value="2" {{determineDefaultSelect '2'}}>2</option>
        <option value="3" {{determineDefaultSelect '3'}}>3</option>
        <option value="4" {{determineDefaultSelect '4'}}>4</option>
        <option value="5" {{determineDefaultSelect '5'}}>5</option>
        <option value="6" {{determineDefaultSelect '6'}}>6</option>
        <option value="7" {{determineDefaultSelect '7'}}>7</option>
        <option value="8" {{determineDefaultSelect '8'}}>8</option>
        <option value="9" {{determineDefaultSelect '9'}}>9</option>
        <option value="10" {{determineDefaultSelect '10'}}>10</option>
      </select>
```

Here is the method:

```
determineDefaultSelect: function(optionText){
    let savedSoftSchedueDays = SoftDueDates.find().fetch()[0].currentSoftMargin;
    if(optionText == savedSoftSchedueDays){
        return "selected";
    }
},
```

On the client side... it ends up loading appropriately and responsively updates in the dropdown when I update the db directly. My problem is that I am getting the following error on load multiple times on load:

> Exception in template helper: TypeError: Cannot read property 'currentSoftMargin' of undefined

While it works, this error does not seem right and this is the only place in the code where `currentSoftMargin` is used. Almost like the template helper `determineDefaultSelect` is running faster than the db call can happen and a product async calls... maybe? Can I prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting this error when the helper runs before the subscription to your data is `ready()`. You can either wait for the subscription is ready to render the template (rendering a spinner in the meantime instead) or defend against the runtime error:

```
determineDefaultSelect: function(optionText){
  const doc = SoftDueDates.findOne(); // equivalent to .find().fetch()[0];
  const savedSoftScheduleDays = doc && doc.currentSoftMargin; // will not error
  return (optionText == savedSoftScheduleDays) ? "selected" : ""; // shorthand
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `{{#if Template.subscriptionsReady}}{{/if}}` in your template to ensure all the data needed are ready.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed! Thx